# phpPgAdmin automatically creates null row during adding a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, phppgadmin

I have a table, called "Route" (part of a production postgres database). Because of a missing column "arrival_time", I used the "Add column" function of phpPgAdmin. There, I added each important property (name, type). When I browse the column after it was created, there is automatically created a value:

```
arrival_time | count
--------------------
NULL         | 9358
```

Because of this, I cannot set the constraint "NOT_NULL", but which is required. What is the reason for this automatically created value? And how can I avoid it or fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a phpPgAdmin issue. You must either add the new column with `NULL` (which is the default anyway), or add with `NOT NULL` constraint **and** a `DEFAULT` clause. If neither is present, PostgreSQL doesn't know what to do with existing rows.

> When a column is added with [`ADD COLUMN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html), all existing rows in the table are initialized with the column's default value (`NULL` if no `DEFAULT` clause is specified). If there is no `DEFAULT` clause, this is merely a metadata change and does not require any immediate update of the table's data; the added `NULL` values are supplied on readout, instead.

If you already added the column, you can use a single `UPDATE` to set all existing rows to a starting value, f.ex.:

```
UPDATE table SET arrival_time = NOW();
```

After that, you can add a `NOT NULL` constraint to this column.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the column and then I added it again with NOW as default and not_null as constraint. After the creation I removed the 'now' constraint. Thx :)